# Multipart Request using Retrofit 1.8.0 not working

Tags: android, multipart, retrofit

I have like 4 days, trying to make a Multipart Request using Retrofit 1.8.0 in android with any success.  My interface looks something like this

```
@Multipart
@POST("/posts/add.json") 
void addComment(
  @Part("id") String id,
  @Part("post[body]") String body,
  @Part("post[attachment]") TypedFile attachment,
  Callback<Map<String, String>> callback );
```

But, in the server side, I receive the following

```
Parameters: {"id"=># <File:/var/folders/z0/0ggjvvfj4t1fdsvbxf3lc9pw0000gn/T/RackMultipart9853-0>, "post"=>{"body"=>#<File:/var/folders/z0/0ggjvvfj4t1fdsvbxf3lc9pw0000gn/T/RackMultipart9853-1>, "attachment"=>#<File:/var/folders/z0/0ggjvvfj4t1fdsvbxf3lc9pw0000gn/T/RackMultipart9853-2>}, "controller"=>"posts", "action"=>"add", "format"=>"json"}
```

As you can see, the file part is sending it in every part but and I'm missing the parameters' value  of id and post[body]

Here it's what Retrofit is trying to send

```
 02-06 15:01:16.213    32545-822/com.myapp D/Retrofit﹕ --fe41634b-6826-4ee4-95cb-65efb0ca66c2
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="id"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 3
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
189
--fe41634b-6826-4ee4-95cb-65efb0ca66c2
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="post[body]"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 4
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
test
--fe41634b-6826-4ee4-95cb-65efb0ca66c2
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="post[attachment]"; filename="IMG_20140203_144358.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpg
Content-Length: 1615460
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
����/�Exif����MM��*���������
```

Here it is what the HttpMime library is sending in the Multipart, the difference is the "Content-Transfer-Encoding" header against Retrofit

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="id"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Content-Disposition: form-data; name=“post[body]"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Content-Disposition: form-data; name=“post[attachment]"; filename="images.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
```

Any clue? Thanks in advance

**-------------------------------SOLUTION----------------------------------**

At the end, I resolved this way, actually my answer is pretty close to @lazypig, it was a good guideline

The only thing that I changed was his class "ByteArrayTypedOutput"

I created a class called "MultipartTypedOutputCustom" http://pastie.org/10549360

And this is, how it looks my interface now

"PostsRetrofitAPI.java" class

```
@POST("/posts/add.json")
    void addComment(@Body MultipartTypedOutputCustom parts,
                    Callback<Map<String, String>> callback);
```

"PostsService.java"class

```
//Properties
private PostsRetrofitAPI mApi;
...

    @Override
        public void addComment(ServiceResponseHandler<Map<String, String>> handler, String id, String body, TypedFile attachment) {
           MultipartTypedOutputCustom parts = new MultipartTypedOutputCustom();
           parts.addPart("id", new TypedString(id));
           parts.addPart("post[body]", new TypedString(body));
           parts.addPart("post[attachment]", attachment);
    objectRetrofitCallback= new ObjectRetrofitCallback(handler, ServerError.class, ClientError.class);
            mApi.addComment(parts, objectRetrofitCallback);
        }
```

Comment: can you post your HTTP envelop? enable logs on the RestAdapter.Builder().setLogLevel(LogLevel.FULL)

Comment: Hi, I already edit my post with your suggestion

Comment: Did you figure it out at the end?

Comment: What was the conclusion to this, I'm on the edge of my seat...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this instead for the interface

```
interface MultipartFormDataService {
    @POST("/{uploadPath}")
    void multipartFormDataSend(
            @EncodedPath("uploadPath") String uploadPath,
            @Body MultipartTypedOutput multipartTypedOutput,
            Callback<String> cb);
}
```

Then later when I call it, it looks like this

```
// creating the Multipart body using retrofit
MultipartTypedOutput multipartTypedOutput = new MultipartTypedOutput();
TypedString idParam = new TypedString("[ID Value]")
TypedString bodyParam = new TypedString("[Body text]")
ByteArrayTypedOutput byteMultipartTypedOut = new ByteArrayTypedOutput(bytes)

// add parts
multipartTypedOutput.addPart("id", idParam);
multipartTypedOutput.addPart("body", bodyParam);
multipartTypedOutput.addPart("attachment", extraParamTypedString);

// send
multipartService.multipartFormDataSend(
                "[TARGET URL]",
                multipartTypedOutput,
            aCallback);
```

My ByteArrayTypedOutput was simple

```
public class ByteArrayTypedOutput implements TypedOutput {

    private MultipartFormMetadata metadata;
    private byte[] imageData;

    public ByteArrayTypedOutput(MultipartFormMetadata metadata, byte[] imageData)
        this.metadata = metadata;
        this.imageData = imageData;
    }

    @Override
    public String fileName() {
        return metadata.fileName;
    }

    @Override
    public String mimeType() {
        return metadata.fileMimeType;
    }

    @Override
    public long length() {
        return imageData.length;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
         outputStream.write(imageData);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you see the examples on http://square.github.io/retrofit/ the object types for your "id" and "part[body]" parameters need to be TypedString and not String. TypedString sets the appropriate MIME type and does the conversion to bytes:

https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit/mime/TypedString.java

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem today to send file and some fields, here is my solution

My interface, TypedFile is a Retrofit class

```
    @Multipart
    @POST("/api/Media/add")
    void addMedia(@Part("file") TypedFile photo,
                  @Part("type") String type,
                  @Part("name") String name,
                  @Part("description") String description,
                  Callback<com.yourcompany.pojo.Media> callback);
```

in Activity

```
profileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent , RESULT_GALLERY );
        }
    });
```

and then

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case RESULT_GALLERY :
            if (null != data) {
                imageUri = data.getData();
                String selectedImagePath = null;
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                Cursor cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(selectedImageUri, null, null,
                null, null);
                if (cursor == null) {
                    selectedImagePath = imageUri.getPath();
                } else {
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
                    selectedImagePath = cursor.getString(idx);
                }
                File file = new File(selectedImagePath);
                waiter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                _YOUR_APP_._YOUR_INTERFACE_.addMedia(new TypedFile("image/*", file), "avatar", "avatar", "avatar", new Callback<Media>() {

                    @Override
                    public void success(Media media, Response response) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

                    }
                });
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Media class is simple pojo to keep answer

```
public class Media {

@Expose
private int[] data;

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The data
 */
public int getData() {
    return data[0];
}

/**
 *
 * @param data
 * The data
 */
public void setData(int[] data) {
    this.data = data;
}

}
```