# Retrofit - @Body parameters cannot be used with form or multi-part encoding

Tags: android, api, retrofit, square

I m trying to make a request in which I want to include a Header , a form-urlencoded field and a json body. 
My Retrofit interface is as follows

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/api/register")
Observable<RegisterResponse> register(
    @Header("Authorization") String authorization, 
    @Field("grant_type") String grantType, 
    @Body RegisterBody body
);
```

When I make this request I get back exception `@Body` parameters cannot be used with form or multi-part encoding.
I have also tried with the `@Multipart` annotation:

```
@Multipart
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/api/register")
Observable<RegisterResponse> register(
    @Header("Authorization") String authorization, 
    @Part("grant_type") TypedString grantType, 
    @Body RegisterBody body
);
```

and I  get an `IllegalArgumentException` and only one encoding annotation is allowed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multipart Request using Retrofit 1.8.0 not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21582453/multipart-request-using-retrofit-1-8-0-not-working)

Comment: also, since it is a multipart, you need several @Part, not a Body and a Part

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This post pointed me to the right direction https://stackoverflow.com/a/21423093/1446856.
I attached everything in the body and send it as a `TypedInput`.
So the interface looks something like this

```
@POST("/api/register")
@Headers({ "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8"})
Observable<RegisterResponse> register(
    @Header("Authorization") String authorization,
    @Body TypedInput body
);
```

and the body looks something like this

```
String bodyString = jsonBody + "?grant_type=" + 
    grantType + "&scope=" + scope;
TypedInput requestBody = new TypedByteArray(
    "application/json", bodyString.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

Comment: what's the value for 'jsonBody'?

Comment: @ViksaaSkool it can be any json string. for instance   {"currency":"GBP", "customerId":2, "country":"GB", "lang":"en-GB", "sizeSchema":"UK", "store":"1"}

Comment: This one not works in Retrofit 2   , we should use RequestBody !!

Comment: what is the value for the bodyString ?
or how to achieve this in retrofit 2 ?

Answer (score 115):

maybe this could help some people, if you have this trouble, you should **remove @FormUrlEncoded** of your interface.

Comment: `@Multipart` would cause the same problem, too!

Answer (score 10):

Adding to Julien's answer, also remove the `@Multipart` annotation. Here's how I have used it:

```
@POST("/app/oauth/token")
Call<AuthResponse> getAuthToken(@Body RequestBody body);
```

And, here is how I have constructed the `RequestBody`:

```
RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                        .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                        .addFormDataPart("grant_type", "password")
                        .addFormDataPart("username", username)
                        .addFormDataPart("password", password)
                        .build();
```

Comment: Cleaner and easier than the accepted answer, works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by adding the field into

```
@POST("/api/register")
```

like this:

```
@POST("/api/register?grantType=value")
```

it's not a good solution, but may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Send Authentication header with json Body to API sample code in Kotlin :

```
 @POST("/api/user/sendlist/")
    fun callSendJsonListPost(
                      @Header("Authheader") header: String,
                      @Body list: StringBuilder
                      )
        : Observable<EntityModelUserslist>
```